# debhelper instructed to use python3, but runs setup.py with python2

Tags: python-3.x, debian, deb, software-packaging, debhelper

I am struggling with `dh` to create package for python 3 (and not for python 2). I use `setup.py` which, when called with `python3`, builds for python 3. I have a separate `debian` directory for py3k, so I want to build just for that version.

`debian/rules` looks like this:

```
export DH_VERBOSE=1
%:
    dh $@ --with python3
```

and `debian/control` has all the usual stuff, including `X-Python3-Version`:

```
Source: woo
Maintainer: Václav Šmilauer <eu@doxos.eu>
Section: python
Priority: optional
Build-Depends: python3-setuptools (>= 0.6b3), python3-all, python3-all-dev, debhelper (>= 7.4.3), libboost-all-dev, pyqt4-dev-tools, libqt4-dev, libqt4-dev-bin, qt4-dev-tools, libgle3-dev, libqglviewer-qt4-dev | libqglviewer-dev, libvtk5-dev, libgts-dev, libeigen3-dev, freeglut3-dev
X-Python3-Version: >= 3.4
Standards-Version: 3.9.1

Package: python3-woo
Architecture: any
Depends: ${misc:Depends}, ${python3:Depends}, ${shlibs:Depends}, python3-xlrd, python3-xlwt, python3-numpy, python3-matplotlib, python3-colorama, python3-qt4, python3-xlib, python3-genshi, python3-psutil, python3-minieigen, python3-imaging, python3-h5py, python3-lockfile, ipython3, mencoder | libav-tools | ffmpeg, python3-prettytable
Description: Discrete dynamic compuations, esp. granular mechanics (python 3)
 ...
```

Now when I run `fakeroot debian/rules binary`, `setup.py` is run with `python` rather than `python3`, despite `--with python3`:

```
$ fakeroot debian/rules binary
dh binary --with python3
   dh_auto_build
pyversions: missing X(S)-Python-Version in control file, fall back to debian/pyversions
pyversions: missing debian/pyversions file, fall back to supported versions
    python setup.py build --force
[...]
```

What's the problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution was to add `--buildsystem=pybuild` to `debian/rules`, so that it looks like this:

```
%:
    dh $@ --with python3 --buildsystem=pybuild
```